# How does where not in rails 3 works

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is a code snippet

```
Wip.where(status: "P").where("reason NOT IN ?", ['DOB_MISSING'])
```

This does not work.

I have tried looking for it and found a lot of questions asked. Some of them have suggested this but I am not sure where I am going wrong

Here I am pasting a part of my rails c

```
[19] pry(main)> Wip.where(status: "P").where("reason NOT IN ?", ['DOB_MISSING']).count
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `wip` WHERE `wip`.`status` = 'P' AND (reason NOT IN 'DOB_MISSING')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''DOB_MISSING')' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `wip`  WHERE `wip`.`status` = 'P' AND (reason NOT IN 'DOB_MISSING')
from /home/ritu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@svasth/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.7/lib/patches/db/mysql2.rb:20:in `query'
```

Comment: does not work? any error?

Comment: @CuriousMind I have added the error part

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple syntax error problem:

```
where("reason NOT IN (?)", ['DOB_MISSING'])
```

All `IN` clauses need to be surrounded by brackets.

Comment: Oh buddy you dont know how much misery I was into right now.. Thanks for showing me the light .. the path to enlightenment :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `arel_table` method:

```
restrict_arr = ['DOB_MISSING']
Wip.where(status: "P").where(Wip.arel_table[:reason].not_in(restrict_arr))
```